# WAR file deploys an innodb Database when I specified it should deploy with myISAM dialect

Tags: hibernate, jpa, innodb, myisam, mysql-5.5

I made a Java EE application and I specified that the database should be of myISAM storage engine:

```
<properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect" />

</properties>
```

When I run my application with this configuration, no table is created in the Database. But when I use the following code:

```
<properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />

</properties>
```

..The application creates tables, but they're in innoDB storage. But I'd like it to be in myISAM, because if I keep the current configuration, this error is generated when I want to make transactions with the database.

```
#1452 - cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails
```

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.1 and MySQL v 5.5.34

I used the solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666269/myisam-dialect-generates-wrong-ddl),

```
 <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="mypackage.MySQL5MyISAMDialect" />

    </properties>
```

but it didn't help because when I want to use it, I get an error telling me that the class `mypackage.MySQL5MyISAMDialect` wasn't found.

Comment: IMO changing the storage engine insn't the way to fix a "foreign key constraint fails" error. The fix is to correct the app so it doesn't put invalid data in the table. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Isn't there another way to do it without changing the app? If there's no way around that, can you give me examples of what I have to change exactly.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what your application is doing, but apparently you have a foreign key constraint which requires that data inserted into table X's field XYZ have a matching row in table Z's field XYZ. Perhaps you're allowing users to type data in for a particular field and they're entering something which doesn't exist, but as I have no access to your database or your application I really can't give you specific guidance.

Comment: Hi,Sorry for this question but  where can i send you my database (db.sql)?